# MongoDB installed successfully on window But folder is not seeing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean

Hello I am new in mean Technology and I want to installed mongoDb and I downloaded msi setup from [link](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center) for bit window.

[image]

I installed successfully  but during installation location of folder not asked and now i don't have idea for the location of mongoDB folder. how to find the mongoDB folder.

Comment: My local instance of MongoDB has been installed to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be installed in Primary Drive. If C drive is primary then Either Directly `C:\MongoDB` or `C:\Program Files\MongoDB`

Comment: can i change this folder location because i want  this location C:\MongoDB

Comment: Once Installed, The answer is no. 
But you can reinstall in your desired location. 
But why C:\MongoDB is your desired location?

Comment: You can  specify an installation directory if you choose the “Custom” installation option. @Qureshi

Comment: i think  because my app in c drive so but i am not sure

Comment: Dont worry about where it is installed. MongoDB is self-contained and does not have any other system dependencies. You can run MongoDB from any folder you choose. You may install MongoDB in any folder like (D:\test\mongodb)

Comment: how to custom installation use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121049/discussion-between-jason-bourne-and-qureshi).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB available either two folder C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86)

Path would be like -> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin

after that you can setup the path using following inputs:

Create directory like -> C:\mongo\data\db
open cmd prompt - > C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin

set the path use below command :
mongod --dbpath=C:/mongo/data/db

Answer (score 0):

uninstalling and installing again worked me to find MongoDb folder in program files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have installed MongoDB 1.4 Stable Community Edition. It is installed at AppData folder which is in my `Users` directory(`c:\Users\MyUser\AppData`). Check that folder on your system.

Comment: That is not what im looking for. AppData files are sperate pal.